# How to find a value in multidimensional-array based on index

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have two multidimensional arrays of the same size. For simplicity, I've now made them with random values, but they are correlated. From the X-array I need to find the maximum value per row. From the Y-array I need the value with the corresponding index as the maximum value from the X-array.

```
import numpy as np

X_splitted = np.random.random_sample([517,56])
Y_splitted = np.random.random_sample([517,56])

rows = len(Y_splitted[0])
colums = len(Y_splitted)

X_max = np.zeros(colums)
index = np.zeros(colums)
Y_corr = np.zeros(colums)

for i in range(colums):
    X_max[i] = max(X_splitted[i])
    index[i] = (np.asarray(X_splitted[i].argmax()))
    index = index.astype(int)
```

I've managed to find the maxima of the X-array and their corresponding indices. However, I am not able to match the Y-array values to these indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close! Just need some tweaking.

Get the index of the maximum value of the X array

```
index[i] = X_splitted[i].argmax()
```

Fetch the same index from the Y array

```
y_val[i] = Y_splitted[i][index[i]]
```

Comment: @Floris user22... is fetching Max Y-value but not the Y-value at the same position of X-max Value. See my answer that gets corresponding value at max X value.

Comment: @ZF007 mind clarifying? My code looks for the index of the max X-value.

Comment: you are searching for the maximum Y value in Y splitted[i] and not the corresponding value in Y_splitted[i] that belongs to the position where X-max is located in X_splitted[i]. Simple example: x = [0, 1, 2, 3], y = [-1,2, 1, 0]. You get with your solution the pair (3, 2) and I am getting (3, 0) as result. Tiny but significant difference between solutions. (x_max,y_max) or (x_max, y_value([i][pos x_max in x_splited[i]]) and thusfar it seems the intention  is the latter solution as stated by OP. I might be wrong... then OP needs to clarify and rewrite the stated problem.

Comment: I'm getting (3,0) as well :). I guess I could've named the variables better - `Y_splitted[i][X_max_index[i]]`

Comment: your code throws an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Z\X\Y\lol.py", line 42, in <module>
    y_val[i] = Y_splitted[i][index[i]]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: Send a link to the full file please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191229/discussion-between-zf007-and-user2248259).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct you want corresponding Y-value to X_max Values. Then see below code with inline comments.

```
...snippet...

for i in range(colums):

#    print (i)
    X_max[i] = max(X_splitted[i])

    X_max_val = X_max[i]                    # this is local X_max value
    j = np.where(X_splitted[i]==X_max_val)  # find local X_max value position in X_splitted[i]

    Y_value = float(Y_splitted[i][j])       # the corresponding Y-value for X_max value.

    Y_corr[i] = Y_value                     # store corresponding y value in own array.

    xy = (X_max_val, Y_value)

    Result.append(xy)                       # joint values in a list.
```